# Can not set the virtual interface for openstack with ansible installation procedure

Tags: networking, server, openstack, administration

I am a bit of a noob, and I am trying to install openstack (xena) on 3 debian machine, respectively named node1, node2 and node3.

By default, all those machines have a fixed ip address (in the dhcp server):

```
node1: 172.0.16.250
node2: 172.0.16.251
node3: 172.0.16.252
---
gateway: 172.0.16.2
mask: 255.240.0.0
---
dhcp server start->finish: 172.0.16.10 -> 172.0.16.249
```

My goal is to simply test openstack. I want to install the infra on node1, compute and storage on node2 & node3.

While following the installation procedure [here](https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/openstack-ansible/latest/targethosts.html), I have to add virtual network. The 3 computers only have 1 ethernet connection each. I use [this](https://opendev.org/openstack/openstack-ansible/src/branch/master/etc/network/interfaces.d/openstack_interface.cfg.test.example) configuration example for my nodes.

When restarting the node, I do not have any connection to internet anymore, nor to the local network.

I understand that I am doing something wrong, and I would like to contact internet from these machines, and contact them from any point in my LAN, so I can install openstack with ansible.

The steps I am following : https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/openstack-ansible/latest/deploymenthost.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ruuning on Hypervisor like Virtualbox try to add a dedicated nat-mode interface for internet access. and multiple interface for your bridges like br-mgmt br-vxlan and ..

Comment: It is bare metal, on three seprate computers

Comment: add interface an make some vlan. consult to your netadmin to deploy a range of ip address per vlan and gw

Comment: You are right, I need at least two nic to make the system work. Thx for the answer.

Comment: yw bro. hope to solve you problem